# asp.net convert anonymous function parameter to string

Tags: c#

How can I get this anonymous function to return "object.Property" as a string?

```
() => object.Property;
```

Thanks!

Comment: What type is `object.Property` to start with?

Comment: I'm trying to pass strongly typed property names to a function. Instead of coding "Article.Title" as a string, I'd prefer to pass ()=> Article.Title.  Is this even clear?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit following clarification of requirements:**

```
var foo = GetYourObjectFromSomewhere();
string bar = ExprToString(() => foo.Property);    // bar = "foo.Property"

// ...

public static string ExprToString<T>(Expression<Func<T>> e)
{
    // use a stack and a loop so that we can cope with nested properties
    // for example, "() => foo.First.Second.Third.Fourth.Property" etc

    Stack<string> stack = new Stack<string>();

    MemberExpression me = e.Body as MemberExpression;
    while (me != null)
    {
        stack.Push(me.Member.Name);

        me = me.Expression as MemberExpression;
    }

    return string.Join(".", stack.ToArray());
}
```

**Original answer:**

<strike>It's not entirely clear what you need, or what the type of `object.Property` is in the first place. Maybe one of the following would do the trick?</strike>

```
// either
() => (string)object.Property

// or
() => object.Property.ToString()
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on your additional explanation and requirements, you can solve this by asking for an `Expression<Func<T, TProperty>>` instaed of a `Func<T, TProperty>`.

You could implement this something like this:

```
public string GetPropertyName<T, TProperty>(Expression<Func<T, TProperty>> propertyPicker)
{
     MemberExpression me = (MemberExpression)propertyPicker.Body;
     return me.Member.Name;
}
```

This would allow you to call it like this:

```
string name = GetPropertyName(x => x.Property);
```

since there exists an implicit conversion from `Func<T, TResult>` to `Expression<Func<T, TResult>>`.

A more complete explanation, as well as a reusable API can be found on [Kzu's blog](http://www.clariusconsulting.net/blogs/kzu/archive/2007/12/30/49063.aspx).